# Top Margin stops centering container

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to replicate the google's homeppage page .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Google</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Gmail</li>
            <li>Images</li>
            <li>App</li>
            <li>Signin</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id = 'container'>
        <h1 id = 'logo'>Google</h1>
        <form>

        <input type = "text">
        <input type = "submit" value = "Google Search">
        <input type = "submit" value = "I'm Feeling Lucky"> 

        </form>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p>US</p>
        <ul class = "left">
            <li>Adverstising</li>
            <li>Business</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>

         <ul class = "right">  
            <li>Privacy</li>
            <li>Terms</li>
            <li>Settings</li>
            <li>Use Google.com</li>
        </ul>
    </footer>


</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is :

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing :border-box;
}

body{
    font-family : arial ,san-serif;
    font-size:13px;
}
#logo {
    background: url('/img/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') top left no-repeat;
    width:269px;
    height:95px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    margin : 0 auto;

}

#container {
    width: 590px;
    margin :0 auto;
    text-align:center;

}

input[type = "text"]{
    width: 590px; 
    padding : 7px;   
    margin:30px 0 ;
    border : solid 1px #eee;
}

input[type = "text"]:hover {   
    border : solid 1px #aaa;   
}

input[type="submit"] {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:13px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-radius:2px;
    color:#757575;
    border-radius :2px;
    fvont-weight:bold;

}
input[type="submit"]:hover {

    border : solid 1px #aaa;
    cursor:pointer;
}

nav {

    text-align: right;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding:7px;   
}
```

For the container div I want to give it top margin and I tried `margin: 80 auto 0;` however this is no longer centers the container and it moves it to the left edge of the body even though it has margin-left/right: auto. I checked in Chrome and the reset rule applied to all elements seems to be applying when the margin top is given. Could somebody please let me know why this is happening? I am new to HTML and CSS and I've spent about 4 hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Did you add the unit after number 80? because its working for me when I do `80px auto 0`

Comment: Thanks , my editor was acting weird . I had the unit but it was not showing in the browser . No idea why that was happening . I edited it using notepad and now the unit is showing up in browser .

Answer (score 1):

For the value of `margin`, use `80px auto 0` and it should work fine. `80 auto 0` is a wrong way to do the thing you were trying to achieve.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: arial, san-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#logo {
  background: url('/img/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') top left no-repeat;
  width: 269px;
  height: 95px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {
  width: 590px;
  margin: 80px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 590px;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
}

input[type="text"]:hover {
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #757575;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav {
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Gmail</li>
    <li>Images</li>
    <li>App</li>
    <li>Signin</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id='container'>
  <h1 id='logo'>Google</h1>
  <form>

    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
    <input type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky">

  </form>
</div>

<footer>
  <p>US</p>
  <ul class="left">
    <li>Adverstising</li>
    <li>Business</li>
    <li>About</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="right">
    <li>Privacy</li>
    <li>Terms</li>
    <li>Settings</li>
    <li>Use Google.com</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```